# Can you direct me to a good implementation of pub sub in java

Tags: java, rabbitmq, publish-subscribe

rabbitmq implementation will help a lot.
10x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a producer-consumer example for RabbitMQ:

http://neopatel.blogspot.com/2009/08/rabbitmq-java-clients-for-beginners.html